# CollectionView doesn't show any CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've created a generic UIView class which contains a UICollectionView inside of it. Just as below. (Class Below also handles the protocols of UICollectionView with Default values)

```
class MyCollectionView: BaseView<CollectionViewModel> {

private lazy var myCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let temp = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout()) // setting initial collectionView
    temp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    temp.delegate = self
    temp.dataSource = self
    temp.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.identifier)
    temp.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return temp
 }() 
}
```

I've created an instance of *MyCollectionView*(class above), and added as subview to the *MainViewController*(Class Below). So doing that made me show a *MyCollectionView* as a subview of MainViewController. I've accomplished so far.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

private lazy var collectionView: MyCollectionView = {
    let temp = MyCollectionView()
    temp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    temp.backgroundColor = .black
    
    
    return temp
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    setUpConstraintsAndViews()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Later on I tried to make *UICollectionViewCell* class and register that to myCollectionView. But still I can not see any cells on my screen. What might I could be missing?

Comment: What's the frame of the collectionView? Are the datasource method called? cellForItemAt, numberOfItemsInSection, etc.?

Comment: @Larme The collection view has constraints instead of frame. It's Constraints are defined as view's constraints. So I t stretches to fill the view. CellForItem at has a dequeReusableCell Which is a custom cell. numberofItemsInSection is static 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyCollectionView` class is not a `UICollectionView`. It does not have a subview of a `UICollectionView` it has a private variable `myCollectionView` that creates a collection view.

As far as I can tell you're adding an instance of `MyCollectionView` as a subview of your `MainViewController`. I don't see how that adds a `UICollectionView` to your view `MainViewController`.

How is the consumer of your `MyCollectionView` supposed to get to the collection view that it owns?

Comment: What I've tried to do is, adding MainViewController a MyCollectionView, which is a UIView, that contains a UICollectionView. Conforming the delegate and datasource inside MyCollectionView to get rid of those functions in MainViewController

Comment: How does your `MyCollectionView` contain a `UICollectionView`? Where is the code that adds the collection view as a subview of your `MyCollectionView`?

Comment: Inside MyCollectionViewClass, like this. Adding inside of the viewDidLoad:

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    setUpConstraintsAndViews()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

Comment: I do get your point. By creating directly a UICollectionView and especially setting a UICollectionViewFlowLayout() directly solves my problem. I was just curious about adding a View ,which contains a UICollectionView as subview, directly to MainViewController might have let me get rid of the UICollectionView Protocols.

Comment: Edit your question to show that additional information. It's frustrating to have to play 20 questions in order to understand the problem somebody is trying to solve. Anyone else reading this thread shouldn't have to wade through a ton of comments either. Provide all the information **IN YOUR QUESTION** that we need in order to understand your setup. Likewise, what is `BaseView`? What is `CollectionViewModel`? Where are the CollectionViewDatasource methods?

Comment: Your `MyCollectionView` class appears to be a UIView, not a `UIViewController`. `viewDidLoad()` is a method of `UIViewController`. That method won't be called on a `UIView`. But you need to edit your question to provide the details we need in order to help you.